# Different authentication for HTTP POST and GET requests in Apache

Tags: htaccess, apache, authentication, post

I want to authenticate for POST requests for `http://path/to/logical/abc.xml` (but not GET requests to that URL).

How do I put constraints like this in place?  The paths are logical and location directive is not supported in `.htaccess`.

Comment: use server side language

Comment: what do you mean by authenticate? ask for user and password or let the request pass?

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this should work. I haven't tested it though.

```
<Limit POST>
Require valid-user
</Limit>
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to let the request pass and be processed, by anything on the server, like perl, PHP, etc, you can something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(HEAD|POST)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

That way you allow POST and HEAD request but block all the rest

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using a PHP server-side script as follows (you may wish to customise/improve the user credentials storage and authentication mechanism somewhat!):

```
<?php
$sRealmName = 'Restricted Area';
$aUsers = array( 'admin' => 'admin', 'guest' => 'guest' );
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) { 

    if( empty( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'] )) {
        header( 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized' );
        header( 'WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="' . $sRealmName
        . '",qop="auth",nonce="' . uniqid() . '",opaque="'
        . md5( $sRealmName ).'"' );
        die( '401 Unauthorized: Login Required' );
    }

    $aParameters = array( 'nonce' => 1, 'nc' => 1, 'cnonce' => 1,
        'qop' => 1, 'username' => 1, 'uri' => 1, 'response' => 1 );
    $sKeys = implode( '|', array_keys( $aParameters ));
    preg_match_all( '@(' . $sKeys . ')=(?:([\'"])([^\2]+?)\2|([^\s,]+))@', 
        $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'], $aMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER );
    $aHttpAuthData = array();
    foreach( $aMatches as $aMatch ) {
        $aHttpAuthData[$aMatch[1]] = $aMatch[3] ? $aMatch[3] : $aMatch[4];
        unset( $aParameters[$aMatch[1]] );
    }

    $aData = $aParameters ? false : $aHttpAuthData;
    if( !$aData || !isset( $aUsers[$aData['username']] )) {
        header( 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized' );
        header( 'WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="' . $sRealmName 
        . '",qop="auth",nonce="' . uniqid() . '",opaque="' 
        . md5( $sRealmName ).'"' );
        die( '401 Unauthorized: Login Incorrect' );
    }

    $sMd5User = md5( $aData['username'] . ':' . $sRealmName . ':' .
    $aUsers[$aData['username']]);
    $sMd5Request = md5( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] . ':' . $aData['uri'] );
    $sMd5Digest = md5( $sMd5User . ':' . $aData['nonce'] . ':'
    . $aData['nc'] . ':' . $aData['cnonce']. ':' .$aData['qop'] . ':'
    . $sMd5Request );

    if( $aData['response'] != $sMd5Digest ) {
        header( 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized' );
        header( 'WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="' . $sRealmName
        . '",qop="auth",nonce="' . uniqid() . '",opaque="' 
        . md5( $sRealmName ) . '"' );
        die( '401 Unauthorized: Login Incorrect' );
    }  
}

header( "Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
header( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . " GMT" );
header( "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header( "Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false );
header( "Pragma: no-cache" ); 
header( "Content-type: application/xml" );
echo( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\r\n" );
echo( '<envelope attribute="value">' . "\r\n" );
echo( '<node attribute="value"></node>' . "\r\n" );
echo( '</envelope>' . "\r\n" );
```

Comment: I edited your post. Take a look at the codeblock. Here you see every line of code is starting with at least 4 spaces. That's the way to make it a code-block. If you paste it from a sourcefile, select everything you've pasted in, and click on the curlybrackets-symbol in the toolbar, just above the editfield, and every selected line will be indented with 4 spaces. read also: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Thank you ExploWare, I've since been using this method or more recent posts but hadn't gone back through historic ones updating formatting (I might do this now). It's a shame there doesn't seem to be colour-coded syntax highlighting available as this can really improve readability greatly.